# Error with TikzEdt after updating LaTeX packages

Tags: tikz-pgf, editors

I upgraded LyX and consequently updated LaTeX packages. After this `TikzEdt` producing compilation error even with new files (see image below). I re-installed `TikzEdt` but no use. I'd highly appreciate if you help me to figure out this problem.

[image]

Comment: Check the settings of TikzEdt. Maybe that is where the problem lies.

Comment: Thanks @azetina. I've resolved the issue by looking at the Setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved the issue by commenting

```
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
```

in `Setting`.